# Knockout js: Conditionally bind title attribute

Tags: html, jquery, knockout.js

I have several tabs at the top of the screen navigating users to several parts of the program.
One of those tabs should now be highlighted if that part of the program has urgent notifications for the user.

I've added a 'notifications' attribute to the #main-header, which is the id for the entire top part div.

The css only items are changing accordingly, so far so good.

However I need to add text to the title attr only if there is any notification for the user.
It is being checked every 10 minutes if there are any notifications.

This top menu is created in a loop looking like this in html:

```
<ul id="navigationMenuTop" class="nav navbar-nav" data-bind="foreach: getRoutes">
        <li data-bind="css: { active: isActive() }, attr: { title: hash === '#url/location' ? setNotificationTitle : '' }">
            <a data-bind="attr: { href: hash }, html: displayName"></a>
```

In the viewmodel:

```
        var self = this;
        self.setNotificationTitle = ko.computed(function () {
            var attr = $("#main-header").attr("notifications");
            if (typeof attr !== 'undefined' && attr !== false) {
                return "NotificationAlert";
            } else {
                return "";
            }
        });
```

Which was created with the help of this: [Knockout.js: conditionally bind title attribute of div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17170938/knockout-js-conditionally-bind-title-attribute-of-div)

The thing is that using setNotificationTitle results in me seeing no tabs at the top at all.
When I simply hardcode text in the html then the top menu gets shown and the tooltip works.

What am I missing?

Edit:
view now looks like this:

```
<ul id="navigationMenuTop" class="nav navbar-nav" data-bind="foreach: getRoutes">
        <li data-bind="css: { active: isActive() }, attr: { title: hash === '#url/location' ? notificationTitle : '' }">
            <a data-bind="attr: { href: hash }, html: displayName"></a>
```

And the viewmodel:

```
    var self = this;
    self.notificationTitle = ko.observable("");

    self.setNotificationTitle = ko.computed(function () {
        var attr = $("#main-header").attr("notifications");
        if (typeof attr !== 'undefined' && attr !== false) {
            self.notificationTitle("NotificationAlert");
        } else {
            self.notificationTitle("");
        }
    });
```

Calls are made to setNotificationTitle whenever the check to see if there are any notifications are made.
This also gives me the same result.

EDIT:
not sure if it matters, but at the bottom of the viewmodel it returns NavigationViewModel like

```
return NavigationViewModel;
```

Changing that to what I see in the knockout js documentation

```
return NavigationViewModel = {
    notificationTitle: this.notificationTitle
};
```

results in errors in the browser for me in system stuff as notificationTitle is undefined which it isn't...

Comment: If `hash` is obervable, you should use `hash()`. If `setNotificationTitle` is observable (or a function that returns a string), you have to call it: `setNotificationTitle()`.

Comment: I can read the hash, the if statement works with hardcoding text. Adding brackets to setNotificationTitle gives me the same result.

Comment: ah, I see you actually included `setNotificationTitle` in your question. Sorry about that. I think the issue is that you're reading from the DOM in your computed. Knockout will never know when it would have to re-check for the main-header attribute. It does not automatically observe your document for changes. The solution would be to flip an observable property when your periodic update runs, rather than just setting an attribute on your header.

Comment: I've added an edit so you can see the changes I did. Now calling setNotificationTitle whenever the check gets done if there are any notifications.

Unfortunately I get the same result

Comment: The observable property would not be readable for css. Css reads this header and changes accordingly things css can change itself. (backgrund color, font color, warning image visible or not) if I do this via code then I need set timeout as the tabs are not loaded when code gets here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eventually this was solved by adding this observable and this function which was called during the check if there are any notifications.

```
        self.notificationTitle = ko.observable("");
    
        self.setNotificationTitle = function () {
            var attr = $("#main-header").attr("notifications");
            if (typeof attr !== 'undefined' && attr !== false) {
                self.notificationTitle("NotificationAlert");
            } else {
                self.notificationTitle("");
            }
        };
```

and adding that like this:

```
<li data-bind="css: { active: (isActive() }, attr: { title: $parent.notificationTitle }">
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're using and updating the DOM to store state. There is no way for knockout to know when you're modifying that state.

Say you have an element on your page:

```html
<div id="stateEl" data-state="1">...</div>
```

You could write a knockout test binding that would work just fine:

```html
<div data-bind="text: document.getElementById('stateEl').dataset.state"></div>
```

This element will render "1" to the page when you call `ko.applyBindings`.

**However**, if you ever change the first element's attribute *after* your call to `ko.applyBindings`, knockout's text binding will not update. Data-binding relies on `ko.observable` properties; knockout does not come with a mechanism to subscribe to changes to the DOM.

So whenever you do this:

```js
document.getElementById("stateEl").dataset.state = 2;
```

The knockout element will still render "1".

### Possible solutions

There are many possible solutions, some more drastic than others. I'll list some in order of my personal preference:

- Stick to knockout.js only. *Do not access or modify the DOM directly via jQuery or any other javascript code*. I.e.: run your periodic updates through a knockout viewmodel and use patterns that work well in knockout to share the data you want to display.
- Make sure your viewmodel instance is accessible to the outside world and ensure the update code notifies it of any new information.
- Implement an additional timed update in your viewmodel that reads from the DOM every x seconds

Here's an example of what that second solution looks like:

```js
// Viewmodel
const vm = {
  notificationCount: ko.observable(0)
}

// Apply bindings
ko.applyBindings(vm, document.getElementById("app"));

// Periodic updates
let i = 0;
setInterval(() => {
  const newCount = i++;
  
  // Update the attribute
  const header = document.getElementById("header");
  header.dataset.count = newCount;
  
  // Update the knockout vm explicitly
  vm.notificationCount(header.dataset.count);
}, 500);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<!-- HTML not bound to knockout -->
<div id="header" data-count="0"></div>

<!-- HTML bound to a viewmodel in knockout -->
<div id="app" data-bind="text: notificationCount"></div>
```